# Ring morphism corresponding to $\text{Spec} k[x, 1/f(x)] \to \text{Spec} k(x)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In section 6.5 of Vakil, he commented that a morphism between function fields doesn't necessarily induce rational maps in the opposite direction. The example he gave was that Spec $k[x]$ and Spec $k(x)$ have the same function fields but there's no rational map Spec $k[x] \to$Spec $k(x)$ over $k$, because then you'll have to define a morphism from an open set of Spec $k[x]$, say Spec $k[x, 1/f(x)]$, to Spec $k(x)$, which corresponds to a ring morphism $k(x) \to k[x, 1/f(x)]$ preserving $k$ and mapping $x$ to $x$, which doesn't exist.

My most likely pretty trivial question is: why does the ring morphism have to map $x$ to $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want not just any ring morphism $k(x)\to k[x,1/f(x)]$, but a ring morphism which induces the identity map $k(x)\to k(x)$ on the fields of fractions of the two rings, since you are trying to get a rational map that corresponds to the identity map $k(x)\to k(x)$ of function fields.  So, your ring morphism $k(x)\to k[x,1/f(x)]$ is required to agree with the identity map on every element of $k(x)$, and in particular on $x$.